# .stopPropagation() and bubbling - can someone explain it to me?

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I have a stupid question. Can somebody explain me, why event still starts on `.outer`? Even when I have set `.stopPropagation()`. I suppose, I don't understand the issue correctly. When I click on `.inner`, event should not bubble up to `.outer`

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">asdsad
    <div class="inner">asdadsasd</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.outer').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.inner').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NGXZ/)

Comment: The problem is that you bind the click handler to .outer, so you just cannot stop the event from bubbling to .outer, because the event already bubbled there (otherwise it wouldn't have been triggered in the first place). See Felix's answer below

Comment: I thought, that event starts on `.inner` first and then bubling up. I have red just know (in jQuery book), that event firstly starts on the specific element and then bubling up. So I am a little bit confused now.

Comment: Yes, bubbling starts on inner elements before going up the DOM tree to the outer (parent) elements. But you bind the click handler to the outer element in your example. So at the time the event handler is triggered, the event ALREADY bubbled up to .outer even if you clicked .inner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$('.inner').on('click', function (e) {   
    e.stopPropagation();
})

$('.outer').on('click', function (e) {   
    $('.inner').toggleClass('hidden');    
})
```

since **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** prevent event buble up not down the DOM tree

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NGXZ/3/)**

Comment: Ok, but when I delete the line with `.stopPropagaton()` in your version, and then click on `.outer`, event does not start and the result is the same as with `.stopPropagation()` [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/9NGXZ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle click on .inner different from click on .outer, you should have two event handlers. In the .inner click handler you can then prevent the event from bubbling up, so that clicking on .inner will not trigger the click event handler on .outer

```
$('.inner').on('click', function(e) {
   ...
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$('.outer').on('click', function(e) {
   ...
});
```